# conditional probability on three variables

Tags: probability

I was trying to understand the relationship between conditional probability and independence under multi variable circumstance. Now I have the following question.

If x,z are independent, y is a function of x

does p(x|y) equal to p(x|y,z)?

My intuitive guess is true but I got stuck in proving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily, because the independence if $X$ and $Z$ neither implies, nor is implied by, the conditional independence of $X$ and $Z$ given $Y$.  We can only claim that equivalence if we know the later.

$$p(x\mid y,z) = \underbrace{\dfrac{p(x,z\mid y)}{p(z\mid y)} {\Large \not\equiv} \dfrac{p(x\mid y)p(z\mid y)}{p(z\mid y)}}_{\text{requires }x\perp z \mid y}=p(x\mid y)$$